# Bottom margins doesn't work. Project in MFC

Tags: c++, printing, mfc, windows-ce

I am working with C++ MFC framework for WindowsCE 2013
My purpose is prepare the correct form of printing.
I initialized `PAGESETUPDLG` structure and initialized it with the following values
Unfortunatelly `psd.rtMinMargin.bottom = 500;` which should have value like 0,5 inch doesn't work.
Regardless of the value set on the printout, it is always 1 inch.
I cannot explain what is the reason for this.

```
BOOL Druk::Configuration()
{
    TCHAR DriverName[256];
    TCHAR DeviceName[256];
    TCHAR OutputName[256];
    ZeroMemory(&psd, sizeof(psd));
    psd.lStructSize = sizeof(psd); // psd is member of PAGESETUPDLG structure
    //psd.hwndOwner = hWnd;
    psd.hDevMode = NULL; // Don't forget to free or store hDevMode.
    psd.hDevNames = NULL; // Don't forget to free or store hDevNames.
    psd.Flags = PSD_INTHOUSANDTHSOFINCHES | PSD_MARGINS;
    psd.rtMargin.top = 100;
    psd.rtMargin.left = 100;
    psd.rtMargin.right = 100;
    psd.rtMargin.bottom = 500; 
    psd.rtMinMargin.bottom = 500;
    lf_vertic.lfHeight = 30; // is member of LOGFONT structure
    lf_vertic.lfWidth = 0;
    //lf.lfOrientation = 2700;
    lf_vertic.lfEscapement = 0;
    lf_vertic.lfUnderline = FALSE;
    lf_vertic.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;
    lf_horizont.lfHeight = 30;
    lf_horizont.lfWidth = 0;
    //lf.lfOrientation = 2700;
    lf_horizont.lfEscapement = 2700;
    lf_horizont.lfUnderline = FALSE;
    lf_horizont.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;
    hFontVertic = CreateFontIndirect(&lf_vertic);
    hFontHorizont = CreateFontIndirect(&lf_horizont);
    DWORD error;
    if (PageSetupDlg(&psd) == TRUE)
    {
        memcpy(&dm, (DEVMODE *)(psd.hDevMode), sizeof(DEVMODE));
        lstrcpy(DriverName, ((TCHAR *)((BYTE *)psd.hDevNames + ((DEVNAMES *)psd.hDevNames)->wDriverOffset)));
        lstrcpy(DeviceName, ((TCHAR *)((BYTE *)psd.hDevNames + ((DEVNAMES *)psd.hDevNames)->wDeviceOffset)));
        lstrcpy(OutputName, ((TCHAR *)((BYTE *)psd.hDevNames + ((DEVNAMES *)psd.hDevNames)->wOutputOffset)));
        //hDC = CreateDC(DriverName, DeviceName, OutputName, &dm); // Wersja dla WinAPI do usunięcia w wersji finalnej
        hDC.CreateDC(DriverName, DeviceName, OutputName, NULL);
    }
    error = CommDlgExtendedError();
    return TRUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-pagesetupdlga

> `rtMinMargin`

> Type: `RECT`

> The minimum allowable widths for the left, top, right, and bottom margins. The system ignores this member if the `PSD_MINMARGINS` flag is not set.

And you do not have that `PSD_MINMARGINS` flag set